# Fetch Past Tweets within Particular Time Period -- Twitter Streaming API

Tags: api, rest, twitter, streaming

I am working on a little app which will give an option to the user to select From and To dates and the app will return tweets they had in the particular time span.

Twitter is offering User Stream API that returns 200 records per request. My account has 6790 tweets and I need to calculate their favorite and retweets.

6790 will result approx 33 requests if I go for all tweets and how much time will it take? Further, will it cause some issue due to twitter rate-limit?

If somebody can please guide me on how can I fetch the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stream for this.

If you want to get the user's favourites, use the [favorites/list](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list)

For example, to get my favourites, call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json?screen_name=edent&count=200
```

If the user has authenticated with you, it's easy to get their retweets with [statuses/retweets_of_me](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets%5fof%5fme)

Comment: But if you mind reading it again, I am saying I need favorites, retweets and tweets for a particular user defined time span. Which is not possible with this list.